# How to translate a link defined in javascript with Drupal.t()

Tags: javascript, i18n-l10n, 9

I have a template string that contains a link, which I want to translate afterwards throught the Drupal UI:

```
var html = `<p>${Drupal.t('<a href="/node/16">Check this out</a>')}</p>`
```

Two questions about that:

1. What is the correct way to build links in JS that could be translatable, (both the `anchor text` and the `href`)?
2. What should I do with these double quotes? Should I escape them? I've noticed in the UI that if I'd escape them with backslashs, each backslash '\' is converted to a triple baskslash '\\\', which makes no sense for me.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```javascript
// Create a <p> tag, append an <a> tag, and make the
// link text translatable:
let html = $("<p/>").append(
  $("</a>", {href:"/node/16"}).text(Drupal.t("Check this out"))
);
```

After that you should clear the cache once, and go to the translate page (/admin/config/regional/translate)